# Can't access MySQL database if including password in connection command

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

If I try to connect with the database including the password in the connection command, I get the following error:

```
mysql -u RdsUser -pRdsPassword -h RdsHost -D RdsDatabase
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'RdsUser'@'RdsHost' (using password: YES)
```

But, if it is not included to be prompted, it works:

```
mysql -u RdsUser -p -h RdsHost -D RdsDatabase
Enter password: 
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2115
Server version: 5.6.19-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

The first case works for me in another MySQL database with version 5.5.40 installed in an Ubuntu server, but in the Amazon's one with version 5.6.19 does not work.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry @MarcB, but you are wrong with that. You can check how to pass the parameter here: http://linux.die.net/man/1/mysql

If you use the short option form (-p), you cannot have a space between the option and the password. If you omit the password value following the --password or -p option on the command line, mysql prompts for one.

Comment: Ah right. too early on monday... guess I'll go get some coffee and wait for the brain to wake up.